# How do I change my navbar's height based on whether a link is in focus?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm using React and javascript to style my webpage, and I have implemented a skip link in my navbar that takes the user further down the page when clicked. This skip link only comes into focus when the user hits the tab key, but it is positioned above the site logo in the navbar and so needs more space when it is visible. I want to increase the height of my navbar when the link is visible, and right now I am using a boolean called linkHasFocus (for some conditional CSS styling), along with a function called checkFocus, to do that:

```
const TopNavbar = styled. div`
      ...
      height: ${props => (props.linkHasFocus ? '9rem' : '4rem')}; 
      ... 
`;
```

And here's the checkFocus function:

```
const checkFocus = () => {
      const elem = document.getElementById('skip-link');
      if (elem === document.activeElement) {
        this.linkHasFocus = true;
      }
      this.linkHasFocus = false;
      return this.linkHasFocus;    
};
```

I then pass this to my TopNavbar component (which is the parent of my skip link component) in my return function like so:

`<TopNavbar linkHasFocus={checkFocus}>`

But it seems the checkFocus function isn't updating the linkHasFocus variable correctly. My understanding of props and javascript in general is a little shaky, so apologies if there's glaring issues here.

Comment: Could you provide more information/code to clarify? I'm not sure if I have understood the question

Comment: Yeah ofc! Essentially my skip link is an <a> tag nested within my <TopNavbar> element, so I need a way to make the height of <TopNavbar> change to 9rem only when the <a> tag has focus.

Comment: I've updated my answer, check if now it addresses what you're trying to achieve or something :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got this navbar example from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/) (I suggest you to check the [Top Navigation tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)), and I've extended it with 3 examples, showing how you can expand it with JavaScript and CSS.
By using the property `.classList` we can `.add()`, `.remove()` or `.toggle()` classes from elements. Then we can add some style content to enhance them (by adding a different height and a transition for the topnav, for example) when a certain action is performed.

The following JavaScript snippet shows 3 examples:

1. expand the Navbar while we are pressing `TAB` key (`keyCode == 9`), and shrink it while that key is up;
2. toggle the expand when the `SPACE` key (`keyCode == 32`) is pressed;
3. expand the Navbar while the mouse is hovering the Skip section, and shrink it while the mouse leaves the area.

```js
// example 1: expand the navbar while tab key is pressed
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 9) {
    document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.add("expand");
  }
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 9) {
    document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.remove("expand");
  }
});

// example 2: toggle navbar expand with space key
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.toggle("expand");
  }
});

// example 3: expand the navbar while the mouse is over
document.getElementById("skip").addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.add("expand");
});
document.getElementById("skip").addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    document.getElementById("myTopnav").classList.remove("expand");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.TopNavbar {
  height: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
#myTopnav.expand {
  height: 9rem;
  transition: height 300ms;
}

.TopNavbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;  
  font-size: 17px;
}

.TopNavbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.TopNavbar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.pageContent {
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="TopNavbar" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a id="skip" href="#skip">Skip</a>
  </div>

  <div class="pageContent">
    <h3>Navbar extension example</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Example 1: extend the navbar while <code>TAB</code> key is pressed.</li>
      <li>Example 2: press <code>SPACE</code> key to toggle the navbar extend.</li>
      <li>Example 3: extend the navbar while the mouse is over "Skip" option.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If that still isn't what you're looking for, you could have a look at [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and search if there's something that suits your page.

Comment: psst, no need to add vendor prefixes to the `transition` property these days :)

Comment: @Leland thank you, you're right! But couldn't that be helpful if we have to use an older browser?

Comment: nah, they can upgrade. it's been over a decade at this point :)

Comment: @Leland I wouldn't rely too much on the average user's ability to stay up to date: remember that today, for many reasons (some are justifiable) the 12% of Windows users still use Windows 7!

Comment: meh. 0.14% of users worldwide use vendor prefixed transitions. this is on par with supporting IE 8. https://caniuse.com/css-transitions